# Passing Query String Param into Response AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have created a mock API within the AWS API Gateway service.

In my GET resource, I have a query string parameter called Id, that I would like to pass from the request into the response, so that whatever Id is entered when invoking the call is returned alongside the dummy data in the API response.

In my Method Request, I have defined a URL Query String Parameter of "Id".

In my Integration Request, in Mapping Templates, I have mapped this input parameter to an element of the same name....

```
{"Id" : "$input.params('Id')"}
```

However, I don't undertsand how to reference this in my Integration Response mapping template. I have tried referenceing "Id" or 'Id', but each time this just returns the text of "Id" or 'Id' rather than the value of Id.

My response mapping template looks as follows....

```
[
 {
  "Data":{
  "ItemId":'Id',
  "name": "Bread",
  "Quantity": 1000
  "Price": 1.50
  }
 }
]
```

I would like to populate "ItemId" with the value of "Id" as entered when invoking the API call.

I have looked through the documentation a bunch of times, but couldn't see how to achieve this.

Help me please SO......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using it in the response as well:

```
[
 {
  "Data":{
  "ItemId": "$input.params('Id')",
  "name": "Bread",
  "Quantity": 1000,
  "Price": 1.50
  }
 }
]
```

A comma is missing after 1000.

You can also use it like this to get all querystring params:

```
{
#foreach($param in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    ""$param"": ""$input.params().querystring.get($param)"" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
}
```

Mapping Templates uses Apache Velocity Template Language (VTL).
http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/vtl-reference.html

**From the VTL site docs:**

Velocity provides an easy way to get the loop counter so that you can do something like the following:

```
#foreach( $customer in $customerList )
<tr><td>$foreach.count</td><td>$customer.Name</td></tr>
#end
```

Comment: Perfect! I don't know why I didn't think to try this. It worked perfectly! Thanks.